# Is there a better way to combine two string sets in java?

Tags: java, set

I need to combine two string sets while filtering out redundant information, this is the solution I came up with, is there a better way that anyone can suggest?  Perhaps something built in that I overlooked? Didn't have any luck with google.

```
Set<String> oldStringSet = getOldStringSet();
Set<String> newStringSet = getNewStringSet();

for(String currentString : oldStringSet)
{
    if (!newStringSet.contains(currentString))
    {
        newStringSet.add(currentString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Since a `Set` does not contain duplicate entries, you can therefore combine the two by:

```
newStringSet.addAll(oldStringSet);
```

*It does not matter if you add things twice, the set will only contain the element once... e.g it's no need to check using `contains` method.*

Comment: Be careful that `newStringSet` is not an Unmodifiable Set.

Answer (score 143):

You can do it using this one-liner

```
Set<String> combined = Stream.concat(newStringSet.stream(), oldStringSet.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

With a static import it looks even nicer

```
Set<String> combined = concat(newStringSet.stream(), oldStringSet.stream())
        .collect(toSet());
```

Another way is to use [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```
Set<String> combined = Stream.of(newStringSet, oldStringSet).flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(toSet());
```

Also any collection could easily be combined with a single element

```
Set<String> combined = concat(newStringSet.stream(), Stream.of(singleValue))
        .collect(toSet());
```

Comment: how is this better than addAll?

Comment: @KKlalala, your requirements will determine which is better.

The main difference between `addAll` and using Streams is: 
• using `set1.addAll(set2)` will have the side effect of physically changing the contents of `set1`.
• However, using Streams will always result in a new instance of `Set` containing the contents of both sets without modifying either of the original Set instances.

IMHO this answer is better because it avoids side-effects and potential for unexpected changes to the original set if it were to be used elsewhere whilst expecting the original contents.

HTH

Comment: This also has the advantage of supporting Immutable Sets. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-

Comment: A word of advice, if you collect to something else than `Set`, add `.distinct()`, because the stream can have duplicates

Answer (score 47):

The same with [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#union-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-):

```
Set<String> combinedSet = Sets.union(oldStringSet, newStringSet)
```

Comment: Sets::union is a great BinaryOperator to use with Collectors.reducing().

Answer (score 14):

From the definition Set contain only unique elements.

```
Set<String> distinct = new HashSet<String>(); 
 distinct.addAll(oldStringSet);
 distinct.addAll(newStringSet);
```

To enhance your code you may create a generic method for that

```
public static <T> Set<T> distinct(Collection<T>... lists) {
    Set<T> distinct = new HashSet<T>();

    for(Collection<T> list : lists) {
        distinct.addAll(list);
    }
    return distinct;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Guava you can also use a builder to get more flexibility:

```
ImmutableSet.<String>builder().addAll(someSet)
                              .addAll(anotherSet)
                              .add("A single string")
                              .build();
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the Apache Common, use `SetUtils` class from `org.apache.commons.collections4.SetUtils;`

```
SetUtils.union(setA, setB);
```

Comment: Note this returns a `SetView`, which is immutable.

Comment: Also obtaining size() from a `SetView` is always a linear operation.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `newStringSet.addAll(oldStringSet)`. No need to check for duplicates as the `Set` implementation does this already.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Since sets can't have duplicates, just adding all the elements of one to the other generates the correct union of the two.

Answer (score 3):

```
 newStringSet.addAll(oldStringSet);
```

This will produce Union of s1 and s2

Answer (score 3):

If you care about performance, and if you don't need to keep your two sets and one of them can be huge, I would suggest to check which set is the largest and add the elements from the smallest.

```
Set<String> newStringSet = getNewStringSet();
Set<String> oldStringSet = getOldStringSet();

Set<String> myResult;
if(oldStringSet.size() > newStringSet.size()){
    oldStringSet.addAll(newStringSet);
    myResult = oldStringSet;
} else{
    newStringSet.addAll(oldStringSet);
    myResult = newStringSet;
}
```

In this way, if your new set has 10 elements and your old set has 100 000, you only do 10 operations instead of 100 000.

Comment: This is a very good logic that I can not imagine why this is not in the main addAll method parametter, like `public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c, boolean checkSizes)`

Comment: I guess because of the specification itself : *Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this collection*. You could have another method indeed but it would be quite confusing if it doesn't follow the same specification than the methods it overloads.

Comment: Yes, I was saying other method overloading that one

Answer (score 2):

```java
Set.addAll()
```

*Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this set if they're not already present (optional operation). If the specified collection is also a set, the addAll operation effectively modifies this set so that its value is the union of the two sets*

```java
newStringSet.addAll(oldStringSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream from Java8 and receive new set

```
Stream.of(set1, set2)
                .flatMap(Set::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```