# Directly assign the result Set of `set1.addAll(set2)`

Tags: java

Let's say I want to calculate the union of 2 sets, `set1` and `set2`, and assign the result to `set3`. I do not want to change the values of `set1` and `set2`.

I know I can do it like this:

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(); set1.add("a");
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(); set2.add("b");

Set<String> set3 = new HashSet<String>(set1); // copy constructor
set3.addAll(set2);
```

But I was wondering if there is a more direct syntax like:

```
Set<String> set3 = (new HashSet<String>(set1)).addAll(set2);
```

or

```
Set<String> set3 = new HashSet<String>();
set3.addAll(set1).addAll(set2);
```

The ways I've tried don't work because `addAll()` returns a boolean, not the result Set object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your criteria are, but here's an alternative:

```
Set<String> set3 = Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you're using Guava, you can also do this:

```
Set<String> set3 = Sets.union(set1, set2);
```

Note that this actually returns a *view*. Subsequent modifications to the underlying sets will reflect in `set3`. If you want an immutable copy, you can use `ImmutableSet`:

```
Set<String> set3 = new ImmutableSet.Builder<String>()
        .addAll(set1)
        .addAll(set2)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be:

```
Set<String> set3 = Stream.of(set1, set2)
                         .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8

```
Set<String> set3 = Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And Java 9

```
Set<String> set4 = Set.of(set1, set2).stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Also, there is a trick with anonymous class.
(As @shmosel suggested in comments this is not good solutions)

```
Set<String> set5 = new HashSet<>() {{
    addAll(set1);
    addAll(set2);
}};
```

Comment: #1 is an exact copy of my answer, #2 is a worse version of Aominè's answer, and #3 is just a bad answer.

Comment: @shmosel "and #3 is just a bad answer." I agree for that.

Comment: The reason I posted the third way is because in the question is asked for "a more direct syntax". And I just tried to compile all options.

Comment: You forgot to include this: `Set<String> set3 = ((Supplier<Set<String>>)() -> { Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); set1.forEach(set::add); set2.forEach(set::add); return set; }).get();`

Comment: If you suggest that I tried to copy you answer. I didn't. I tried all ansers myself. Also, there is similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30139228/2564509 or this source http://www.techiedelight.com/merge-two-sets-java/ .

Comment: I added notes in my answer you suggested. Thank you for that.

Comment: For the last technique, I needed a `String` inside `new HashSet<String>()`

Comment: @wisbucky Check your compiler level. Since Java 7 there is diamond operator.