# How to merge two unmodifiable Sets in Java?

Tags: java, merge, java-stream, java-11, unmodifiable

How to merge two `unmodifiable static final` sets?

```
public static final Set<Long> ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = Set.of(COMPANY_GST, GOVERNMENT_BODY_GST);

public static final Set<Long> INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = Set.of(BUSINESS_PAN, INDIVIDUAL_PAN);
```

I want to combine the above static final sets into one set (one-statement initialization), because it's a `Class` variable

```
public static final Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = ?
```

Comment: create another set @Thirumal

Comment: `SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD  =  Stream.concat(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD.stream(),INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: *Why* is this getting downvoted? Just look at the weak answers - this trivial problem has no neat JDK-only solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better way to combine two string sets in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30139228/4207306)

Comment: @Eklavya the accepted answer in the link does not support `Unmodifiable Sets`.  @youcef-laidani answer below returns an Unmodifiable Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-statement initialization, if preferred:

```
public static final Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = 
     Collections.unmodifiableSet(
        Stream.of(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD, 
                  INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD)
              .flatMap(Set::stream)
              .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Or, perhaps more readable:

```
public static final Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD;
static {
    Set<Long> all = new HashSet<>();
    all.addAll(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD);
    all.addAll(INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD);
    
    SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = Collections.unmodifiableSet(all);
}
```

Ignore the `Collections.unmodifiableSet` call if the third set is not expected to be unmodifiable.

Comment: Since this is joining two sets created via `Set.of(…)`, the OP might want to use the collector `Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()` instead of `Collectors.toSet()`, to get a set with the same semantics (wrapping it in `Collections.unmodifiableSet(…)` becomes unnecessary then). Likewise, the alternative might use `Set.copyOf(…)` instead of `Collections.unmodifiableSet(…)`. It may cause a little higher initialization time, which is compensated with potentially higher performance in the subsequent runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Stream#concat is useful too

```
Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD  =  
         Stream.concat(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD.stream(),
                       INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: The resulting `Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD` may be backed by a modifiable set (most likely a HashSet). May be better to `.collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet())`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use streams:

```
public static final Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD =
    Stream.of(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD, INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or, in your case, and as mentioned in comment, you can use [**Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableSet()) :

```
public static final Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD =
    Stream.of(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD, INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
```

Comment: I like this one the most but improve with `Collectors.toImmutableSet()` (introduced in Java 10)

Comment: I meant `Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()`

Comment: Thank you @drekbour, this is interesting also :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out that Guava still handles this case more more readably (and probably much more performant) than the JDK-only solutions:

```java
public static final Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = ImmutableSet.builder()
    .addAll(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD)
    .addAll(INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you can't create a third set and just add both of the two final sets?

```
Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = new HashSet<>();
SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD.addAll(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD);
SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD.addAll(INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD);
```

The first two sets' being `final` just means that you can't modify *those* sets.  It does not prevent you from reading the sets into another new collection.

Comment: `Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = new HashSet<>(ORG_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD);SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD.addAll(INDIVIDUAL_SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD);`

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen `Set.of()` returns an Unmodifiable Set, while `final` prevents the variable being reassigned. From the question, `public static final Set<Long> SUBSCRIBER_ALLOWED_NUMBER_CD = ?` needs to be assigned on one line or in a static block, like @youcef-laidani or @ernest_k.